# Grow a tree from parent relations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming

I have the following data:

```
data Item a = { id :: ID
              , parentId :: Maybe ID
              , data :: a
              }

data ItemTree a = ItemTree ID a [ItemTree a]
```

And I want to to have this function: `buildForest :: [Item a] -> [ItemTree a]` which will return a non-trivial forest (that is, a respect parent relations). I can assume that `ID` for each item is unique, and that all items have their parent the list, if that matters.

I've been trying to wrap my mind around this for several days now. I've implemented a similar code in javascript by mutating the objects (in fact, a copy of them), but I would have liked to know how can this be done Haskell.

My best thoughts on the topic so far where this:

```
toRelations :: Item a -> ((ID, ID), Item a)
toRelations it@{id, parentId} = ((parentId, id), it)
```

So now I can have a list of relations from parent to children, So the arrows point at the right direction. I still need to construct a tree from it, while avoiding doing slow lookups. Does that make sense?

Comment: I would approach this in two steps:  First, find all the roots of the result forest by identifying all `ID`s that are never used as a `parentId`.  Once you have that list, recursively construct the tree from each root by scanning the input items to find the children of the current node. Each step is O(n^2) done naively, but could be improve to O(n log n) by pulling in appropriate data types like `Data.Map`.

Comment: Whoops. My description for how to handle roots is actually how to find leaves. Slightly backwards. At least roots are easier to find. Just O(n), even in the naive case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a functional language, you write such a program by keeping a state which you pass around as a function parameter. In this case, the state is the 'current' item at which you're looking.

```
import Data.Maybe (isNothing)
import Data.Tree

type ID = Int

data Item a = Item
  { _id :: ID
  , _parentId :: Maybe ID
  , _value :: a
  } deriving (Show)

type Items a = [Item a]
type ItemTree a = Tree (ID, a)

buildTreeFrom :: Items a -> Item a -> ItemTree a
buildTreeFrom m (Item i _ v) = Node (i,v) (map (buildTreeFrom m) . filter ((== Just i) . _parentId) $ m)
```

Note that this relies on your stated assumptions. The algorithm is simple and follows directly from the requirements of the function:

- the value of the current node is the ID/value pair of the given `Item`
- the subforest of the current node is all of the trees whose root nodes' parent IDs are the ID of the current node

Then the function you want simply calls `buildTreeFrom` on every `Item` which is a root node (i.e. which has no parent):

```
buildForest :: Items a -> Forest (ID, a)
buildForest m = map (buildTreeFrom m) . filter (isNothing . _parentId) $ m
```

And a simple test (using the very handy `Data.Tree.drawForest`):

```
>test0 = [ Item 0 Nothing 'a', Item 1 (Just 0) 'b', Item 2 (Just 0) 'c', Item 3 (Just 1) 'd'
        , Item 4 Nothing 'a', Item 5 (Just 4) 'b', Item 6 (Just 5) 'c', Item 7 (Just 6) 'd' ]
>putStrLn $ drawForest $ (fmap.fmap) show $ buildForest test0
(0,'a')
|
+- (1,'b')
|  |
|  `- (3,'d')
|
`- (2,'c')

(4,'a')
|
`- (5,'b')
   |
   `- (6,'c')
      |
      `- (7,'d')
```

Note that I've made no effort to optimize this program. If you think it's too slow, profile first!

Comment: If you use [`Map.fromListWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:fromListWith) to organize the list of items into a map from each id to the list of its children, and then use that map to `buildTreeFrom` instead of filtering, you will get an asymptotic speedup -- I think from n^2 to n log n.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `[Item a]` to `Map (Maybe ID) [Item a]`, keyed on the parent ID of each item.

Now you will have the roots under `Nothing`, and for each root ID you can pull its children from the map (dict) with [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:lookup), and populate the tree's next level this way, recursively.

To be used as key in `Map`, `ID` must be in `Ord`. I think it's a reasonable assumption. I'll use `Int` here:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Maybe (maybeToList)

type ID = Int

data Item a = Item { id :: ID
                   , parentId :: Maybe ID
                   , payload :: a
                   } deriving Show

data ItemTree a = ItemTree ID a [ItemTree a] deriving Show

buildForest :: [Item a] -> [ItemTree a]
buildForest items = map mkTree roots
   where
   -- dict :: Map.Map (Maybe ID) [Item a]
      dict  = Map.fromListWith (++) [ (parentId i, [i]) | i <- items ]
      itemsUnder k = join . maybeToList . Map.lookup k $ dict
      roots = itemsUnder Nothing 
      mkTree item =                 -- using `dict`, recursively build the tree
        ItemTree (id item) (payload item) 
               . map mkTree $ itemsUnder (Just $ id item)
```

Here instead of passing the dict around, we have it in (shared, inner)  scope.